# Get index of elements in Pandas Dataframe by condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C '], 
index=['D', 'E', 'F'], data = np.arange(0, 9, 1).reshape(3,3))

   A  B  C 
D  0  1  2
E  3  4  5
F  6  7  8
```

what I need is to extract row and column indices for all elements if they are,say, less than 4. It seems basic, but I cannot do it.

what i would like to have is, for example:

```
 {'D A': 0, 'D B':1,...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly mask values greater or equal than 4 as `np.nan`, then use `stack` method which by default drops `nan` values, now if you extract the index, it would be the indices you needed:

```
df.where(df < 4).stack().index.values
# array([('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C '), ('E', 'A')], dtype=object)
```

If you need the value for each pair of indices as well, you can convert it to a dictionary:

```
df.where(df < 4).stack().to_dict()
# {('D', 'A'): 0.0, ('D', 'B'): 1.0, ('D', 'C '): 2.0, ('E', 'A'): 3.0}
```

where `df` as follows (values less than 4 highlighted):

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'color: %s' % 'red' if x < 4 else '')
```

[image]

Comment: can I get it in form of a data structure? Cause I need to process the results

Comment: You can convert the stack result to a dictionary using `to_dict` method. See the update.